# Using a Django admin list view in my own templates?

Tags: django, forms, templates

I know it's a newbie question, but, I want to render a tabular list view of a model in one of my own templates.

It seems like it should be a no brainer to pick up the form from the admin interface rather than write my own. Have I got the wrong idea here?

As usual, the documentation seems to take me so far and...

If this is a sensible approach how do I go about it?
If it is not - are there good snippets available?

Answer (score 5):

I made the mistake when beginning with Django of thinking in terms of the django-admin for everything. Try treat the admin as "just another app". What are you trying to do? Do you just want to list the objects for a particular model? If so, that's quite easy to write it manually:

**views.py**

```
def list_objects(request):
    return simple.direct_to_template(request,
        template='folder/templ.html',
        extra_context={
            "objects" : MyModel.objects.all().order_by('some_field')
        })
```

**templ.html**

```
...
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ object.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

On the other hand, if you want to add functionality like add/delete/edit objects then it's a little more complicated. You need to create the forms for your models, along with a few more views to take care of the different tasks.

Django tries to make life easy when doing these repetitive by offering **[generic_views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/)**. Have a look though and you will see they take some of the pain out of having to write CRUD (create, update delete) interfaces etc.

Comment: Thanks pastylegs - I want to render a list view of objects with filtering and sorting just as in the admin. It seems like those elements could be lifted from the admin - or can I find one I can plug in to my app? I'm excited by my early experiences with django as compared with other frameworks, but I'm still finding my feet with development patterns etc.